# Draw an empty graph using Matplotlib?

Tags: python

I want to draw an empaty graph chart. Date and time should be in Y axis and Kilometers in X axis. For reference please refer the image. I do not need blue graph line. [image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the right way, but I kinda cheated with a subplot.

```
import pylab as plt

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1),(0,0))
plt.xlim([0, 100])
plt.ylim([0, 750])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

As similar to Amiga500, I added the x-axis date labelling and the titles for axes.

```
import pylab as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
x=[] #to define an empty list for x-axis data

#iterations for the string of datetime
year = str()
month = str()
t = str()
date_list = []
for i in range(0,6):
    for j in range(1,13):
        year = str(2004 + i)
        month = str(j)
        t = year + '-' + month + '-' + '1'
        date_list.append(t)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1),(0,0))
plt.ylim([0, 750])
plt.xticks(x,date_list)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(len(date_list)-1))
plt.xticks(rotation=45) #make the x-axis label inclined to 45 degrees
#show the title of x and y axes
ax1.set_xlabel('Date & Time')
ax1.set_ylabel('Kilometers')
plt.show()
```

This is the output blank plot.
[image: Output plot]